# Halachic status of malawach

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, mezonot-beracha

What bracha do we make on [malawach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malawach)? Does it have the same status as bread, or do we treat it as a cake or cookie?

Comment: Are you using water or juice to mix with the flour ? Or is it a giant pancake from filo dough ?

Comment: what is milawi? malawa7? if it is, anything you dip you should wash for. even an apple which you dip in honey. also malawa7 is used as a bread type not a cookie.

Comment: −1: question doesn't explain what milawi is. (Just in case it's obvious to everyone else and I'm ignorant, I checked [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/milawi) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/milawi), but they have nothing.) I'd even vote to close as "unclear what you're asking", were my vote not binding.

Comment: Further comments are at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13002840#13002840 et seq.

Comment: I think it's clear what Milawi is.

Comment: I'd never heard of milawi before this post.

Comment: Also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35542

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://nightintunisia.blogspot.co.uk/2005/03/oranges-dates-and-milawi-oh-my.html) is the definition of milawi.

> a certain flatbread called Milawi (Mill-ay-wee) made its way into the
>   cities. It is flour and water made into a dough and then folded over
>   and over with copious amounts of olive oil until it is slick, firm and
>   elastic. Then it is stretched to about 10 inches and thrown on an
>   inverted metal disk (looks like a reshaped, burnt hubcap - probably
>   is) that is resting over a gas flame, and cooked until it is dark on
>   both sides.

From [yeshiva.co's Rabbi Moshe Leib Halberstadt](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=5107): are the principles of making the brocho

> In a regular case where one uses soya, canola or vegetable oil which
>   do not have a very dominant taste, and with the amount necessary for
>   making dough, the taste of the dough is principal and it is classified
>   as proper bread for which the blessing is Hamotzie Lechem Min
>   Ha’aretz. But in a case where one uses a large amount of oil which has
>   a very strong taste such as olive oil, and the taste of the oil is
>   more dominant than the taste of the dough, it is considered snack
>   bread for which the blessing is Bore Minei Mezonot.

The questioner at yeshiva.co was asking about ground sprouted wheat  but the answer does not appear to be specific to that sort of flour.