# What bracha is made on these culturally Sephardic foods?

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

What bracha is made on

1. Kibbe?
2. Lachmajin?
3. Jachnun?

And, for each of the foods, why this is so?

(I do not know what these foods are made but they taste great.)

Comment: Also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34411

Comment: A bracha is based to some degree on ingredients so I would suggest looking up what is in each in order to get a lead on what bracha to make. The culture from which a food comes has no bearing on what bracha to make.

Answer (score 5):

Kibbeh is meat deep-fried in a cracked-wheat shell, and Lahme Baajin is like a mini-pizza but made with meat.

As Kibbeh are flour based and fried, they are Mezonot. Lahme Baajin are baked, but because they are stuffed with a filling, they fall under the category of "Pat Haba BeKisnin" and are Mezonot.

Sources: The Shulchan Aruch and my Sephardic-ness.